# Downloading an SVG as a PNG at a Specific Size via Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, png

I am trying to set up a generator to let people custom build wallpapers for their phones.  At the moment I have them doing the customizing by editing an svg template by changing the colors and text through a form which is working perfectly.

Then once they click submit they are prompted to download their wallpaper as a png. Once the button is clicked I am drawing the svg to a hidden canvas and then the png begins downloading from there.

I am using a link to multiple Adobe fonts for the styling of the wallpaper. The problem is, every time I attempt to download the PNG from mobile or a smaller window size, if I was using one of the adobe fonts, the font gets swapped.

The hidden canvas is width 1125px and height 2536px and I have the custom svg fit to match the size. I have little experience with Canvas so I am not sure what to do but my best guess is that the problem lies in the size of the canvas.

This is the code I have for my download. If you need more information please let me know but my goal here is to get this to work so that the png will be downloaded in high quality from any size window.

```
    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var svg = document.getElementById('bg2');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

function triggerDownload (imgURI) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
  });
    if(document.getElementById("name").value=="null" || document.getElementById("name").value=="") {
    var un = "MakeAGraphic";
  } else {
    var enteredName = document.getElementById("name").value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    var un = `${enteredName}_MakeAGraphic`
  }
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('download', `${un}.png`);
  a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    var imgURI = canvas
        .toDataURL('image/png')
        .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

    triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };

  img.src = url;
});
```

Comment: Where's the font code?

Comment: It's in the header code for the page.  I re-created the issue in Codepen using one of the jersey style wallpapers.  Thought that may be a more efficient way. https://codepen.io/coach_grantjr/pen/RwKqyXM

Comment: So when you create the blob there's no font information in that blob, because there was no font information in the data object. You'd need to make sure you serialised a data URL containing the font data into the blob.

Comment: Ok. I added the font to the svg via @import and I'm getting the same issue. It's updated in the pen. Is that not what you meant? Sorry to be dense all of this is new to me.

Comment: the SVG must be self contained so what does the @import look like? Does it use a data URL?

Comment: Here is the line of code containing the font at the beginning of the SVG. 
`<svg id="bg2" fill="#222" viewbox="0 0 1125 2436" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
<defs>  
<style>  
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/fov0mgf.css");</style>  
</defs>`

Comment: `https://use.typekit.net/fov0mgf.css` is not a [data URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: Oh. Ok. Like I said this is all really new to me.  Do you have any suggestions on how to get the data URL?

Comment: If the font licence permits you to do so you could simply download the font data and convert it using an online converter to base64

Comment: Thanks! You've been incredible.  One final question, for base64, do I need to include the entire base64 code? Or can I store it elsewhere and reference it? Or is there a way to compress it at all? I'm ending up with a massive base64 code.

Comment: the SVG must be self contained, so no the massive solution is the only way to go.